# i want to send notification to particular user through one signal

Tags: php, onesignal

I am using one signal for sending notification , I am new to this notification through one signal is working for all users, now I want to send notification to particular user so how can I identify those user with my server and one signal.

also I want to make custom api for this suppose one user had sent request to another user so that user get notification on his device through one signal how can I perform this?? help?

```
$fields = array(
        'app_id' => "",
        'include_player_ids' => array(""),
        'data' => array("foo" => "bar"),
        'contents' => $content
);
```

How to identify the particular user from my server?

Comment: you use a unique id to identify each user

Comment: can u explain lil more??

Comment: did you read the one signal documentation? https://documentation.onesignal.com/v5.0/reference#section-send-to-specific-devices

Comment: @madalinivascu What method we can use to get UserID from OneSignal in WebView? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72656494/how-to-fetch-user-id-from-onesignal-using-javascript